# add data.frame column by using a look up table and linear interpolation

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm sure this a very common method but I'm having trouble stating it accurately. I have a long `data.frame` with three columns: a date_time column, a numeric column (`df$property1`), and a string column.

I have another `data.frame` serving  as a lookup table providing a relationship between "property1" and another numeric property, "property2".

I'd like to add a `df$property2` column to `df` that is an approximated result of using linear interpolation of `df$property1` based on the lookup table's property1 and property2 relationship. For example, if `df$property1` happened to be 10, `df$property2` would be 20, or if `df$property1` happened to be 145, `df$property2` would be an somewhere under but pretty close to 1500.

I'm hoping to learn how to create `df$property2` efficiently and am interested in learning `tidyverse` and non-tidyverse methods.

```
library(tidyverse)

# create example data frame needing new column
date_time <- seq(from=as.POSIXct("2015-12-10 12:00", tz="GMT"), 
to=as.POSIXct("2015-12-10 18:00", tz="GMT"), by="1 hours") 
property1 <- c(1,45,12,99, 105,3,149)
df1 <- data.frame(date_time, property1) %>% mutate(class = "a")
property1 <- c(50,10,66,147, 11,190,80)
df2 <- data.frame(date_time, property1) %>% mutate(class = "b")
df <- rbind(df1, df2)

# create example look up table
property1_lookup <- c(1,     10, 15, 50,  100, 150,  99999)
property2_lookup <- c(0.001, 20, 30, 100, 500, 1500, 1501)
lookup <- data.frame(property1_lookup, property2_lookup)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Check out the `approx()` or `approxfun()` functions. Those seem like they would do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is fairly straightforward:

```
df$property2 = approx(x = lookup$property1_lookup,
                      y = lookup$property2_lookup,
                      xout = df$property1)$y
head(df)
#             date_time property1 class  property2
# 1 2015-12-10 12:00:00         1     a   0.001000
# 2 2015-12-10 13:00:00        45     a  90.000000
# 3 2015-12-10 14:00:00        12     a  24.000000
# 4 2015-12-10 15:00:00        99     a 492.000000
# 5 2015-12-10 16:00:00       105     a 600.000000
# 6 2015-12-10 17:00:00         3     a   4.445222
```

I'll leave it to you whether or not linear interpolation is appropriate... from your data a logarithmic interpolation might do better.

Comment: thank you @Gregor.   From the first output row, it looks incorrect to me, though, with property1 being 10 and property2 being 0.1 and not 20. Thanks also for the logarithmic option - these data are purely for example but a good reminder.

Comment: actually @Gregor, it works fine, I think the bad output is just from the previous, now-deleted question I posted before I shortened & changed the vectors.